# Nested collections (Dictionary<int, List<string>>) do not get properly passed to query string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, query-string, .net-5

I have a post action which, on success, populates a new view model: `ConfirmationViewModel.cs`. This view model contains a property called `Wings`, which is nothing more than a dictionary with `int` as its key type and `List<string>` as its value. After successfully passing the required data to this view model, the action redirects to another action, passing the view model with it.

As you can see in the image below however, the Dictionary is not successfully populated in the next request. I therefore suspected that something went wrong within the process of binding query string parameters to the view model.

[image: Debug info]

The query string however showed the real problem however:

```
https://localhost:44341/ShipRegistration/Confirmation?Hull=Neptunus&Engine=Galaxy%20Class&Wings=%5B1,%20System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D%5D&Wings=%5B2,%20System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D%5D&TotalWeight=908&TotalEnergy=186
```

, or URL-decoded:

```
https://localhost:44341/ShipRegistration/Confirmation?Hull=Neptunus&Engine=Galaxy Class&Wings=[1, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]&Wings=[2, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]&TotalWeight=908&TotalEnergy=186
```

Somehow, the nested collection's value is not properly passed to the query string. Instead, only the object's type is passed (`System.Collections.Generic.List`).

I know that making use of sessions would make my life a whole lot easier at this point, but using sessions or any other form of persistence is unfortunately not an option for me.

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo to pass dictionary within query string:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestDictionary(ConfirmationViewModel c) 
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

ConfirmationViewModel :

```
public class ConfirmationViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Wings { get; set; }
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public string Hull { get; set; }
        public int TotalEnergy { get; set; }
        public int TotalWeight { get; set; }

    }
```

Url:

```
https://localhost:xxx/xxx/xxx?Hull=Neptunus&Engine=Galaxy%20Class&TotalWeight=908&TotalEnergy=186&Wings.1=s&Wings.1=ss&Wings.2=r&Wings.2=rr
```

result:
[image]

You can also use url like this:

```
https://localhost:xxx/xxx/xxx?Hull=Neptunus&Engine=Galaxy%20Class&TotalWeight=908&TotalEnergy=186&Wings[1]=s&Wings[1]=ss&Wings[2]=r&Wings[2]=rr
```

or

```
https://localhost:xxx/xxx/xxx?Hull=Neptunus&Engine=Galaxy%20Class&TotalWeight=908&TotalEnergy=186&Wings[1][0]=s&Wings[1][1]=ss&Wings[2][0]=r&Wings[2][1]=rr
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. You did specify what the URL should look like, but not necessarily how to achieve it. In the meantime, I have found a workaround: I could just render a view without actually submitting a new request. Thank you for your time and effort and my apologies for the late reply.